# Add multiple attendees to Meeting Invite

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I tried to add multiple attendees but only the last email address is stated in the .To area.

Test 1:

```
    .RequiredAttendees = "me@me.com;"

    .RequiredAttendees = "you@you.com"
```

Test 2:

```
    .RequiredAttendees = "me@me.com; you@you.com"
```

The full code:

```
Sub MeetingInvite()
Dim rng As Range
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(1)
On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .RequiredAttendees = "me@me.com;"
    .RequiredAttendees = "you@you.com"
    .Subject = "Meeting"
    .Importance = True
    .Body = "Meeting Invite" & Format(Date)
    .Display
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
Unload Emy
End Sub
```

I need to add roughly 30 email addresses.

Comment: `.RequiredAttendees = "me@me.com; you@you.com"` works for me

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oi4hi.png

Comment: Thanks -- let me test this some more and come back. I appreciate the confirmation. Byc hance, is there a maximum number of emails I can add?

Comment: The MSDN indicates that you should use the form you've used in test 2. It also says that these are only display names and you should be using a `Recipients` collection. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/appointmentitem-requiredattendees-property-outlook

Comment: `is there a maximum number of emails I can add?` See [THIS](https://www.vircom.com/blog/how-many-email-addresses-can-outlook-hold-in-the-to-cc-bcc-fields-individually/)

Comment: I've used the recipients for a mass email generation. I will take a look this but .RequiredAttendees = "me@me.com; you@you.com" is failing to work with multiple people.

Comment: I actually figured a more efficient way fr me to add emails within the active workbook. I've tried a few configurations of this:         Set myRecipient = .Recipients.Add(Range("C2")) but it's not pulling more than the first cell. For example,         Set myRecipient = .Recipients.Add(Range("C2:C10")) fails to pull all of the email addresses. This would only pull the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to change the RequiredAttendees. This property only contains the display names for the required attendees.

The attendee list should be set by using the Recipients collection. 
Try this:

```
With OutMail
    .Recipients.Add ("me@me.com")
    .Recipients.Add ("you@you.com")
    .Subject = "Meeting"
    .Importance = True
    .Body = "Meeting Invite" & Format(Date)
    .Display
End With
```

Or if you want to read the attendees from a sheet:

```
With OutMail
    For Each cell In Range("C2:C10")
        .Recipients.Add (cell.Value)
    Next cell
    .Subject = "Meeting"
    .Importance = True
    .Body = "Meeting Invite" & Format(Date)
    .Display
End With
```

Of course, if you really want to invite 30 attendees by mail, it might be wise to schedule that meeting a couple of days ahead, in stead of inviting them for today ...