# Using Excel to Send Appointments/Meetings with Attendees on Outlook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, office-automation

what I have running currently only sends myself the meeting.  I tried doing xOutItem.Send rather than xOutItem.Save and get an error.  I have an attendee email on H2, but they don't receive the message on their calender.  Any tips/help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```vb
Sub AddAppointments()

    Dim I As Long
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xOutItem As Object
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xRg = Range("A2:H2:A3:H3")
    For I = 1 To xRg.Rows.Count
        Set xOutItem = xOutApp.CreateItem(1)
        Debug.Print xRg.Cells(I, 1).Value
        xOutItem.Subject = xRg.Cells(I, 1).Value
        xOutItem.Location = xRg.Cells(I, 2).Value
        xOutItem.Start = xRg.Cells(I, 3).Value
        xOutItem.Duration = xRg.Cells(I, 4).Value
        If Trim(xRg.Cells(I, 5).Value) = "" Then
            xOutItem.BusyStatus = 2
        Else
            xOutItem.BusyStatus = xRg.Cells(I, 5).Value
        End If
        If xRg.Cells(I, 6).Value > 0 Then
            xOutItem.ReminderSet = True
            xOutItem.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = xRg.Cells(I, 6).Value
        Else
            xOutItem.ReminderSet = False
        End If
        xOutItem.Body = xRg.Cells(I, 7).Value
        xOutItem.RequiredAttendees = xRg.Cells(I, 8).Value
        xOutItem.Save
        Set xOutItem = Nothing
    Next
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem.requiredattendees#:~:text=This%20property%20only%20contains%20the%20display%20names%20for%20the%20required%20attendees.%20The%20attendee%20list%20should%20be%20set%20by%20using%20the%20Recipients%20collection.  `RequiredAttendees`  "This property only contains the display names for the required attendees. The attendee list should be set by using the Recipients collection"

Comment: @TimWilliams Interesting.  Think something like this will do the trick?                         Set myRecipient = xOutItem.Receipients.Add ("H2")
        xOutItem.Send

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47610632/add-multiple-attendees-to-meeting-invite

Answer (score 0):

The [AppointmentItem.RequiredAttendees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem.requiredattendees) property returns a semicolon-delimited string of required attendee names for the meeting appointment. This property only contains the display names for the required attendees. The attendee list should be set by using the `Recipients` collection.

You may find the [How To: Fill TO,CC and BCC fields in Outlook programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/08/outlook-fill-recipients-programmatically/) article helpful.